# Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero usar $_SESSION para guardar los datos del incio de sesion hasta que se cierre el navegador, pero falla con lo que tengo

el select y todo lo demas para el inicio de sesion funciona, solo falta el SESSION pero no se como hacerlo, ayuda, muchas gracias a todos de antemano

el error que me da es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\TFG\inicioSesion.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\TFG\inicioSesion.php on line 14

```
 <?php

include_once 'config.php';
session_start();

$email=$_POST['email'];
$contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

$sql = "SELECT email, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";

$result =  $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $result['email'];
  echo 'Sesión iniciada correctamente';
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: me muestra esto antes de intentar hacer el session: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } @BetaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realizas un `var_dump()` a `$result` verás que la salida es algo similar a esto:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Entonces es *comprensible* el mensaje de error pues no puedes obtener el valor de la clave `email` de un array que no esta existente en la salida mostrada.

Dado lo anterior, entonces puedes valerte de [**`fetch_assoc`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) el cual te ayudará a obtener el resultado de tu consulta como un *array asociativo*

Quedando así:

```
$result =  $conn->query($sql);
$filaValoresObtenidos = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Y si realizas el mismo procedimiento de volcado para ver su contenido ahora tendrías algo como esto:

```
array(2) {
  ["clave1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["clave2"]=>
  string(8) "2"
}
```

Llegados a este punto ahora si podrás recuperar el valor de la clave deseada de esta forma:

```
$filaValoresObtenidos["email"];
```

*Es importante acotar que procedí de esta forma atendiendo a que según lo expuesto parece tu query solo regresa una fila, en caso de que retorne N filas entonces deberás iterar (checa la documentación enlazada para mas detalles)*.

Te anexo el comentario de *A.Cedano*, quien expone algo muy importante:

> Simplemente query() devuelve un objeto mysqli_result el cual representa un conjunto de los resultados obtenidos en la consulta. Y ese objeto tiene métodos específicos para leer los datos, uno de los cuales es fetch_assoc(). El resultado de query() no son los datos en sí mismos, sino un objeto que apunta hacia los datos y se debe usar uno de los métodos de ese objeto para obtener los datos.

Comment: Creo que faltan detalles en tu respuesta que ayuden a OP a entender cómo funciona mysqli. Simplemente [`query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) devuelve un objeto [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) el cual representa un conjunto de los resultados obtenidos en la consulta. Y ese objeto tiene métodos específicos para leer los datos, uno de los cuales es `fetch_assoc()`. El resultado de `query()` no son los datos en sí mismos, sino un objeto que apunta hacia los datos y se debe usar uno de los métodos de ese objeto para obtener los datos.

Comment: Agregaré tu comentario @A.Cedano y te citaré